# How are stuck at faults in a combinational circuits considered

Tags: digital-logic, testing, boolean-algebra

I came over this example given in literature explaining the stuck at faults (possible) to be considered in a combinational circuit. I don't understand why g, h, i nodes in the circuit are considered seperately... If its because those correspond to a particular Logic gates design fault.. then why wasn't a stuck at fault considered for the last outermost NAND gate whose output is "z" as shown ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to check the consequences each individual stuck-at fault separately, a stuck at (0 or 1, to be considered separately) of the h input affects only that input. Likewise, a stuck-at of the i input affects only that input. A stuck-at of the g output affects both the i and h inputs, so these are 3 different cases (6 cases when 1 and 0 are considered separately).

For the j output a stuck-at has the same effect as a stuck-at of the connected input of the final NAND, so there is no need to consider these separately.

Comment: As "h", "i" nodes are shorted(taking into consideration only stuck at faults, no loose connections), "h" stuck at 0 is "i" stuck at 0... and this effects both the paths...How does "h" input affect only that input of the gate.. why not other gate whose input is "i" ?

Comment: A 'stuck-at-X' of an input has the effect that the input behaves as if it is permanently at the X level. It is a model. If you want a physical interpretation, see it as an error in the input stage of the gate. The error that you describe (short circuit of the wire) is modeled by the stuck-at error of the corresponding output.

Comment: Ok.. so single stuck at fault is not just, that node being 1 or 0 by some connections... but only that node being such without effecting other connections(inputs or outputs of gates connected to that node by wires)... ? Definition misunderstanding...

Comment: For an input, yes, but an output that is stuck-at will defintely influence the inputs that it connects to.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuck-at_fault):

> A stuck-at fault is a particular fault model used by fault simulators and automatic test pattern generation (ATPG) tools to mimic a manufacturing defect within an integrated circuit. Individual signals  and pins are assumed to be stuck at Logical '1', '0' and 'X'

They are just used to just model the fault (they are not pin-pointing the fault). Stuck at '1' (and stuck at '0') fault at node j and and the point marked with the arrow have the same effect on all the nodes in the circuits. So they are equivalent faults. We can model it by using single stuck at faults.

On other hand stuck at faults at node a, node c and node d will produce different effects in the other nodes in the circuit and hence they are modeled as three different stuck at faults.

The way I think is: *You can model a stuck at fault at every interconnect.*