# How many stuck at faults are present in this circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, testing, boolean-algebra, vlsi

I was given a Verilog code of a circuit and was asked to find the number of stuck-at faults. 
The code was

```
NOT INV1 (Y1, A);
NOT INV2 (Y2, A);
NOT INV3 (Y3, A);
```

I have attached two different ways in which the circuit can be drawn and so I am getting two different answers.

[image]

In figure A, there are totally four different wires at the input side and so 4 fault locations at the input side (one is between input A and point x, one between point x and input of gate 1, one between point x and input of gate 2 and one between point x and input of gate 3).

In figure B, there are five different wires at the input side and so 5 fault locations at the input side(one between input A and point x, one between point x and input of gate 1, one between point x and point y, one between point y and input of gate 2 and one between point y and input of gate 3).

**The same logic circuit has two different answers. Which one is correct?**
Or in other words, in reality how the given logic is fabricated? Will the connections be like in figure A or figure B?

I have marked the fault locations with a pencil mark in both the circuits.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Actually I miss the actual question. I don't see answers as stated in the bold sentence, so I'm unable to say whether or not a [missing] question is correct or not.

Comment: @try-catch-finally what I mean to say is, according to figure A, there are 4 fault locations and according to figure B, there are 5 fault locations. But both the figure represents the same logic. So the answer depends on how we draw it and not just the logic right?

Comment: "In figure A, there are totally four different wires at the input side... In figure B, there are five different wires" - no, in both cases there is only _one_ wire. The schematic tells you nothing about _how_ input A gets to the 3 gates, only that they are all joined together. And since they are joined together, a stuck-fault in one place on the wire is on _all_ of them.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Please take a look at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159308/how-are-stuck-at-faults-in-a-combinational-circuits-considered where the stuck-at faults at location g, h and i are considered as seperate things.

Comment: You can get an answer of 3 too if you connect pin to pin, daisy-chain, on the invertors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you consider each input separately rather than the wires themselves, and additionally if there is more than one input connected to the wire, you count the output driving the wire as well. So on the input side you have one output `A`, and three inputs (one for each inverter), giving a total of four locations.

Comment: "g, h and i are considered as seperate things" - yes, but h and i are _gate inputs_, not wires. A stuck-at fault between between x and y is the same as one at A because they are the same wire and a stuck-at anywhere on the wire has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have input coming in on the bottom.  It is equivalent to Figure B, but it gives you a third option.

From: [faults in digital systems](https://www.slideshare.net/agyemanh/fa-31428491)

[image: Single Stuck-At Faults]

The difference between the two is just layout (which ultimately you have no control over).  I'd go with Fig A, since you have one input, three input devices and three outputs.  That would give 7 test points and 14 states.

Remember, the goal is to identify test patterns which detect chip faults, with a minimum of states.  In your case, a 1 or 0, should produce corresponding 0 and 1 on all outputs.  Whether one or more gates are effected by a fault is immaterial.